# Dropdown not getting validated

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. For some reason the dropdown isn't getting validated correctly because it should be coming up with an error message saying this field is required but its not. It should be just like this page for the dropdown.

http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/peach/forms.html

```
<?php echo form_label('Recipient', 'recipient'); ?>
<?php 
$options = array();
$options[0] = '<option></option>';
foreach($users AS $user)
{
    $options[$user->user_id] = $user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name;
}
?>
<?php echo form_dropdown('recipient', $options, -1, 'class=required'); ?>
```

Comment: Without seeing what html that form_dropdown function builds, sorry, can't help. But it does seem odd that you embed `<option>` in element 0, but raw names in the rest of the entries. Shouldn't that be `<option>$user->blahblah</option>`?

Comment: Well I put that because its an empty value. If you notice on the template it shows Select an Option which in the html is an empty option tag.

Comment: Yeah, but why do you put in `<option>` tag text for the 'blank' value, but not for the rest of the names you're putting into the list?

Comment: the value of the options are the $user->user_id

Comment: you're not understanding. `$options[0] = '<option>'; $options[1] = 'john doe'`. Why do you put the literal `<option>` tag into the blank element, but don't wrap any of the names with options?

Comment: I have no idea I guess. Here's what is getting rendered. http://jsfiddle.net/tNFNY/  So your saying I should?

Comment: No idea, just pointing out that it's weird. i'm not going to wade through a wall of html to find where the options are.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8883/discussion-between-user1244239-and-marc-b)

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your form_dropdown() function. When you pass the class as a string in the fourth parameter you also need to wrap the 'required' in quotes, the HTML won't validate otherwise.  Change the last line to this:

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('recipient', $options, -1, 'class="required"'); ?>
```